# Как в Angular получить куку и сохранить её?

Tags: cookie, angular, httpclient

Я пытаюсь извлечь куку, так как используя стандартный httpClient Angular, куки не сохраняются и получить я их не могу.
Я пишу так

```
public urlapi = 'https://server.com/api';
  private httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'X-SourceId': '11111111111'
    })
  };  //если я добавлю withCredentials: boolean, то сервер не отдаёт данные

this.http
      .post(this.urlapi, postBody, this.httpOptions)
      .pipe(map(data => { ........... }
```

Данные то я получаю, а заголовки не могу получить, да и куки не перезаписываются сами. Что можно сделать? Спасибо

Comment: ты не вытащишь куки из хедеров и тебе не нужно их сеттить вручную, их сеттит браузер если они есть в заголовке `set-cookie`. Для примера - так работают некоторые openid клиенты и их механизм рефреша токена (если токены в куках)

Comment: @overthesanity так вот прикол в том, что здесь браузер их не добавляет, когда использую клиент ангуляра, а в других всех ситуациях они добавляются

Comment: ну это не проблема httpclient'а, потому что это всего лишь реактивная обертка поверх xmlhttprequest. А что значит _в других всех ситуациях они добавляются_?